# CMS for blog, with internationalization and code formatting

Tags: asp.net, internationalization, content-management-system, blogengine.net

I'm looking for a CMS for a small programming blog/personal website.

Requirements are:

- free to use (preferably with access to source)
- support for code formatting
- support for internationalization of both content and interface
- preferably written in asp.net
- many themes to choose from, available on the Internet
- as simple as possible (eg. don't need to customize layout other than choosing a theme and modules on sidebar)

My first choice was BlogEngine.NET, but it turned out it doesn't support internationalization of content (or does it?).

Does somebody know something that would meet above requirements?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at http://orchardproject.net/ It's free supports internationalization and is well documented.

Comment: I'll check it out and report back to You.

Comment: I can't set it up so it would show posts only in one language on home page. I installed Localization and Culture Picker modules. Is it possible?